# Как сделать 301-ый редирект для адреса, содержащего точку, на страницу с ошибкой 404?

Tags: .htaccess, редирект, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-301

Редирект со страниц с точкой

```
http://web-site.com/index.phpsad
```

На 404 страницу

```
http://web-site.com/404
```

Answer (score 1):

### Сама постановка задачи в корне неверна

Правильнее будет поступить так:

- Если страница не существует, но у нас есть новая подходящая страница с очень похожим содержимым, тогда мы можем сделать перенаправление с кодом состояния 301, как бы говоря «перемещено навсегда».
- Если страница не существует, и мы понятия не имеем, почему кто-то набрал никогда не существовавший или неправильный URL в адресной строке, тогда необходимо вернуть код состояния 404 «не найдено». Это означает, что введен неправильный URL и кто-то дал вам ошибочную ссылку. С этой страницы не следует делать автоматических редиректов на другие страницы. Вместо этого лучше разместить ссылку на главную страницу, чтобы пользователь мог сам выбрать, что ему дальше делать.
- Если страница не существует, но нам достоверно известно, что когда-то такая страница была, однако сейчас ее нет и не будет в будущем (мы решили, что такая страница нам больше не нужна), тогда необходимо вернуть код состояния 410 «удалён» со ссылкой на главную страницу, чтобы пользователь мог решить, что ему делать дальше.

Делать редирект с кодом состояния 301 на страницу с 404-ой ошибкой **неправильно**. На ней нет максимально похожего содержимого на то, что сейчас не существует. Следует сразу возвращать 404-ую ошибку при обращении к таким адресам. Склейка несуществующих адресов с 404-ой ошибкой не даст ничего в SEO.

Коды состояния HTTP существуют не просто так, это стандарт, которого следует придерживаться.

В описании [**стандарта**](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) и на [**вики**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP) вы найдете больше информации.
Прочитайте статью от Google: "[**Do 404s hurt my site?**](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2011/05/do-404s-hurt-my-site.html)"

### Решение вашей проблемы

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule [.] /404 [L]
```

Так будут обрабатываться все страницы, содержащие в своем адресе точку, кроме существующих файлов и папок, в имени которых есть точка.

Пример работы скрипта:

```
/test.sub/ # Не существующий раздел - 404 Not Found
/test.h    # Не существующий файл   - 404 Not Found

/catalog.example/ # Существующий раздел - 200 OK
/index.html       # Существующий файл   - 200 OK
```

---

При ответе использована информация из ответа на вопрос: "[**SEO - 301 redirect via 404 page**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21690988/2486051)"